# Trying to fix a malformed SQLite database. Keeps encrypting itself with an unknown password

Tags: database, encryption, sqlite

I'm using sqlite3.exe like this, to fix a malformed database:

```
sqlite3 sv.db
.output fixed.db
.dump
```

However, when I open fixed.db in DB Browser for SQLite, it asks me for a password, and if I `.read` it with sqlite3.exe, it says "file is not a database".

```
sqlite3 fixed.db

sqlite> .read fixed.db
Error: near line 3: file is not a database
...
```

The original database has no encryption, and shouldn't. How do I remove the encryption or disable any new encryption?

Answer (score 0):

The complete error message is:

> file is encrypted or is not a database

So the problem is not encryption, but that the file is damaged to begin.

Please note that `.dump` does not output a database but a text file containing SQL commands to recreate the database.

Please note that `.read` expects a text file containing SQL commands, not an actual database file.

Comment: Of course the file is damaged? There's a rogue table in there that I'm trying to drop, but can't, because it's malformed. The way to "drop" it is to use `.dump` to recreate the database _without_ the table.

Comment: Edit the question to show how exactly you tried to use `.read`.

Comment: Edited with that

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is right here before your eyes:

```
sqlite3 fixed.db

sqlite> .read fixed.db
```

You open the **dump**, which is an invalid DB file as CL. already pointed out, then try to import it again. What you probably want to do is creating a new DB file, then import the dump:

```
sqlite3 sv-fixed.db

sqlite> .read fixed.db
```

A word about file extensions: Don't use the same extension for binary database files and SQL dumps/scripts - for obvious reasons considering the confusion above. I suggest to use

- `.sqlite` for binary SQLite databases.
- `.sql` for SQL scripts.

If you're working with different DBMS' at the same time you can expand this convention.

Comment: Thanks, but after doing `.read` again it just produces a blank, 0 byte database. The .sql file actually contains SQL, too, which is odd. Also, .db is the file extension used by the game the database file is for.

Comment: @Billy Works for me. Check again: what's in the dump?

Comment: So many SQL statements my Notepad++ almost crashes! Is there another tool I could use (that wouldn't take years) to import the data?